# Reassign pandas series values using nested defaultdict

Tags: python, pandas, mapping, transform, defaultdict

I'm working on an NFL dataset and want to do the following mapping for every play in the df:

- I'm trying to populate a column (`DistToRusher`) with the distance of each player to the rusher of that play.
- The `DistToRusher` column is currently populated with player ids.
- I'm trying to map these player ids to the ones in the inner dictionary keys and replace them with the inner dictionary values.
- I have a defaultdict-of-dictionaries `dist_dict` that looks like this:

```
    dist_dict = {play_id1: {player_id1: distance, player_id2: distance ...}, 
                 play_id2: {player_id1: distance, player_id2: distance ...}...}
```

Here is my code:

```
def populate_DistToRusher_column(df):
    for play_id, players_dict in dist_dict.items():
        df[df.PlayId == play_id].replace({'DistToRusher': players_dict}, inplace=True)
    return df
```

This code runs, is slow (20-30s), and doesn't change `DistToRusher` column; when I inspect the df, `DistToRusher` still contains the player id numbers and not the distances.

Here is a toy version of the actual data:

```
from collections import defaultdict 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'PlayId': {
  0: 20170907000118, 1: 20170907000118, 2: 20170907000118,
  22: 20170907000139, 23: 20170907000139, 24: 20170907000139},
 'NflId': {0: 496723, 1: 2495116, 2: 2495493,
  22: 496723, 23: 2495116, 24: 2495493},
 'NflIdRusher': {0: 2543773, 1: 2543773, 2: 2543773,
  22: 2543773, 23: 2543773, 24: 2543773},
 'DistToRusher': {0: 496723, 1: 2495116, 2: 2495493,
  22: 496723, 23: 2495116, 24: 2495493}})

dist_dict = {20170907000118: defaultdict(float,
             {496723: 6.480871854928166,
              2495116: 4.593310353111358,
              2495493: 5.44898155621764}),
 20170907000139: defaultdict(float,
             {496723: 8.583355987025117,
              2495116: 5.821151088917024,
              2495493: 6.658686056573021})}
```

Comment: check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html  you should be able to accomplish this with a map and use the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @oppressionslayer, but it's still returning the same results even when I map it.

Comment: if you could post a partial of your data: df[0:10].to_dict() and the inner key/values you use, i could take a look at it further

Comment: @oppressionslayer thanks for the help! I updated the question with a miniaturized version of the actual data.

Comment: Let me know if my answer is right. I think that's what your looking for, if not let me know what i need to change. thx!

Comment: Neat question, I tried to edit the statement so the generic aspect is clearer, it's essentially asking for mapping using a nested (default)dict. Also: for generality and correctness, what should happen if `player_id<n>` is longer active, e.g. left the pitch/injured/substituted? Presume you want to get NaN?

Comment: So you want to do a 2D lookup of `dist_dict` first by `NflIdRusher` then by `NflId`. Which cannot easily be done with a simple `df['NflIdRusher'].map(...)`. Really I think you want your `dist_dict` to provide a multikey lookup: `dist_dict.get(key1, key2, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is right, IIUC:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(dist_dict)
df['DistToRusher2'] = df.apply(lambda x: temp[x.PlayId][x.NflId], axis=1)

or

df['DistToRusher2'] = df.apply(lambda x: dist_dict[x.PlayId][x.NflId], axis=1)
```

output:

```
            PlayId    NflId  NflIdRusher  DistToRusher  DistToRusher2
0   20170907000118   496723      2543773        496723       6.480872
1   20170907000118  2495116      2543773       2495116       4.593310
2   20170907000118  2495493      2543773       2495493       5.448982
22  20170907000139   496723      2543773        496723       8.583356
23  20170907000139  2495116      2543773       2495116       5.821151
24  20170907000139  2495493      2543773       2495493       6.658686
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @oppressionslayer! This worked like a charm:

```
df['DistToRusher2'] = df.apply(lambda x: dist_dict[x.PlayId][x.NflId], axis=1)
```